# Ultra small http server with support for Lua scripts

Tags: apache, lua, embedded, freertos

I have a Renesas R5F571M processor that has 4MB of flash and 512K of RAM.
I need to run FreeRTOS and also have a web server that can run Lua scripts in order to interface to the hardware with custom C code.

Can anyone suggest a very compact HTTP+Lua server that I could use.
The Barracuda Application Server looks ideal but at around $20K is way out of my reach.
I would love to be able to use Nginx and PHP but the resource constraints preclude that option.

Answer (score 1):

I once upon a time, worked with the [Lighttpd](https://www.lighttpd.net/) web server. You could compile it under certain conditions to a binary as small as, ~400KB size (400KB << 4MB). On the backend you could interface it to the [fastCGI](http://cgi.sourceforge.net/) C-library. The backend then you can write in C.

You can skip the Lua scripts in my opinion. Or if you still want to use them, you could use the Lighttpd `mod_magnet` module which can work directly with Lua, so you can skip the FastCGI library. It also has a smaller memory footprint than `Nginx`, although I am not sure if it is small enough to fit in the 512KB RAM.

p.s. Lighttpd is free.

Answer (score 0):

on the compact side:

- bozohttpd http://www.eterna.com.au/bozohttpd/ HTTP/1.x webserver that can run lua scripts but forks with every request so it's stateless in that sense
- lhttpd https://github.com/danristea/lhttpd HTTP/1.x HTTP/2 webserver that was inspired by bozohttpd but integrates lua coroutines with an event system (kqueue/epoll) to achieve non-blocking stateful execution.

(disclaimer: I am the author of lhttpd)